# Sockets - Simple C# Server and JAVA Android Client

Tags: java, c#, android, sockets

I'm trying for sometime now and I cant figure it out why this is not working.

CLIENT:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Socket socket;
public static final int PORT = 6000;
public static final String server_IP = "192.168.2.30";
public String mensagem = null;
public String mensagem_final = null;

Button btn_conetar;
TextView txt;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn_conetar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_conetar);
    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);

    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                while(!isInterrupted())
                {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            txt.setText(mensagem_final);
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();


}
public void onClick(View view)
{
    new Thread((new ClientThread())).start();
    //Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
   // startActivity(i);
}

//Thread que inicia o socket
class ClientThread implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try
        {
            InetAddress serveradress = InetAddress.getByName(server_IP);
            Log.e("TCP","A conetar...");
            socket = new Socket(serveradress,PORT);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            while((mensagem = in.readLine()) != null)
            {
                mensagem_final += mensagem;
            }


            if(in.readLine() == null)
            {
                Log.e("TCP","Nao tem mensagens");
            }
            Log.e("MSG",mensagem);

            socket.close();
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

}

Server:

```
    Servidor servidor = new Servidor();
    servidor.serverthread();



class Servidor
{

   public void serverthread()
    {
        Thread serverthread = new Thread(server);
        serverthread.Start();
    }


    public void server()
    {

            Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            TcpListener tcplistener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 6000);
            tcplistener.Start();


            TcpClient tcpclient = tcplistener.AcceptTcpClient();

            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            NetworkStream ns = tcpclient.GetStream();

            string welcome = "Ola";
            data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(welcome);
            ns.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

    }
}
```

Any idea why I cant receive the string "Ola" in my android application? It doesnt give me any error, it just doesnt do anything.
My internet's default adress is 192.168.2.1.

Good links are also welcome.

Comment: Have you tried using a packet sniffer to see what's actually being sent back and forth? Can you hit any breakpoints in the server?

Comment: I havent tried yet. Do you recommend anything? I only know Wireshark

Comment: looks like there isnt anything being sent to port 6000

Comment: On your desktop machine, `telnet localhost 6000` and make sure you can connect and receive "Ola". Easy way to make sure the server part is working before you debug the Android client.